# How to add a default character for commenting in eclipse with pydev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I want eclipse to comment my code when I press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> in the next way

```
#.
```

instead of the usual

```
#
```

I searched in the eclipse preferences but found nothing, any ideas?

Comment: There's no way to configure that. To change that, you'd need to change the code of PyDev itself.

Comment: That was my guess but was hoping that was not the case